# Example of matrices A, B, and row-echelon form matrix C | A and B are row-equivalent to C, but not to each other

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm struggling to come up with example matrices A, B, and C, where C is in Row Echelon Form, A is row-equivalent to C, B is row-equivalent to C, but A and B are not row-equivalent.

In general, I concede that this question is solved by accepting that the Row Echelon Form is not unique.  However, while I accept that in general (because row operations can manipulate the remaining triangle), I don't understand how that applies to the above problem.

So far I've hit a wall by examining
$A =\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 2 \\
  3 & 4
 \end{bmatrix}$ and 
B = $\begin{bmatrix}
  5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8
 \end{bmatrix}$

But A and B are both reducible to $I_2$, so I haven't guessed a good A and B.

I'm fully willing to accept that I'm not seeing something simple, but alas, I am not seeing it, and have come to the Interwebs for assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean [this definition of row equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_equivalence), you'll note that the page states that row equivalence is an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation).  Among other things, equivalence relations are *transitive*, so if $\sim$ is our equivalence relation (so $A\sim B$ means $A$ and $B$ are row equivalent), then $\sim$ being transitive means that $A\sim B$ and $B\sim C\implies A\sim C$.

Let's put this into the language of your question:  We know that $A\sim C$ and $B\sim C$.  Another property of equivalence relations is that they are *symmetric*, meaning that if $A\sim B$ then $B\sim A$.  Getting back to your question, we know that $B\sim C$, so we also have that $C\sim B$.  Finally, as $A\sim C$ and $C\sim B$, through the transitive property we know that $A\sim B$.  This implies that you won't be able to find a counterexample, so shouldn't be too frustrated that you weren't able to.

Comment: This is the answer; The issue as discussed with my professor is that the original question contained a typo.  Specifically, the question should have read "If matrices A and B are row equivalent to the same matrix C, which is in row echelon form (REF), then A and B are <strike>row</strike> equivalent," to which the answer would have been false because A and B can represent different linear systems, and thus would each have unique solutions for their respective systems.

Answer (score 3):

Is this a true-false question? Because I think the statement that "when C is in Row Echelon Form, A is row-equivalent to C, B is row-equivalent to C, but A and B are not row-equivalent" is incorrect, therefore you will not be able to find any examples.
Simply put, two matrices are row equivalent if and only if one may be obtained from the other one via elementary row operations.
If A is row-equivalent to C, by the definition, there are elementary matrices $E_1, · · · , E_k$ such that$$A=E_1· · ·E_kC$$ If B is row-equivalent to C, by the definition, there are elementary matrices $F_1, · · · , F_k$ such that$$C=F_1· · ·F_kB$$
Substituting we get $$A=E_1· · ·E_kF_1· · ·F_kB$$Since $E1, · · · , Ek, F1, · · · , Fj$ are elementary matrices, by the definition, A is row
equivalent to B.

Comment: Indeed, this is a true-false question: reproduced here since I may have inartfully conveyed it initially: "If matrices A and B are row equivalent to the same matrix C, which is in row echelon form (REF), then A and B are row equivalent"